# Excel VBA Macro find and replace nextRow nextColumn

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my task:

Sheet2: Column A will contain string that i want to find in Sheet1 and replace with the values given in Columns B to myLastColumn.

Sheet1: Column A will contain identical string from row 1 to myLastRow. Each cell will contain string found in Sheet2, column A. I want to replace this string with values from Sheet2, Columns B to myLastColumn. However;

Sheet1, Cell A1 will be replaced by values in Sheet2, column B.

Then, Sheet1, Cell A2 will be replaced by Sheet2, column C.

Then, Sheet1, Cell A3 will be replaced by Sheet2, Column D.

This will continue until the lastrow is reached in Sheet1 and the last column is reach in Sheet2.

Here is an example:

Contents of A1: "A B C D E F G H I J",replaced with the contents ColB Sheet2,
Contents of A2: "A B C D E F G H I J",replaced with the contents ColC Sheet2,
Contents of A3: "A B C D E F G H I J",replaced with the contents ColD Sheet2,

I have started with the code below but I keep getting an error. Unfortunately I am unable to pinpoint the cause. I know thats not a direct question, but can someone help me with achieving my stated task?

```
Sub myReplace()

    Dim myDataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim myReplaceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim myColumn As Long
    Dim myLastColumn As Long
    Dim myFind As String
    Dim myReplace As String

'   Specify name of Data sheet
    Set myDataSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

'   Specify name of Sheet with list of replacements
    Set myReplaceSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

'   Assuming list to search start in column A on row 2, find last entry in list
    myLastRow = myReplaceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'   Assuming list of replacement start in column B on row 2, find last entry in list
    myLastColumn = myReplaceSheet.Cells(Columns.Count, "2").End(xlToLeft).Column

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Loop through all list of replacments
    For myRow = 2 To myLastRow
    For myColumn = B To myLastColumn
'       Get find and replace values (from columns A and B)
        myFind = myReplaceSheet.Cells(myRow, "A")
        myReplace = myReplaceSheet.Cells(myRow, myColumn)
'       Start at top of data sheet and do replacements
        myDataSheet.Activate
        Range("A1").Select
'       Ignore errors that result from finding no matches
        On Error Resume Next
'       Do all replacements on column A of data sheet
        Columns("A:A").Replace What:=myFind, Replacement:=myReplace, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
'       Reset error checking
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next myColumn
    Next myRow

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Replacements complete!"

End Sub
```

[image][image]

Comment: There is a question missing somewhere in this...

Comment: Sorry, i have now added.

Comment: Hi again, you seem to have added the same screenshot twice. What is the error message you are getting and where in the code? I'm still struggling to understand what you want to do, maybe a have-want screenshot would help.

Comment: The error says: object defined error. Also, here is the link for the screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/v9ejB

Comment: I also created an example in the question. If it helps.

Comment: Still struggling to understand exactly what you're after, but it is starting to feel like you just need a lookup, rather than VBA code? Can you please post something that shows what a row in sheet 1 should look like? Thirdly, where in the code does it throw the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the definition error in your code it is because your are incorrectly using Cells:

This:

```
myLastColumn = myReplaceSheet.Cells(Columns.Count, "2").End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Should be:

```
myLastColumn = myReplaceSheet.Cells(2,myReplaceSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Cells reference is Cells(row, column). Row would also be numeric if you are starting row 2, not "2".

How to achieve your overall aim is a different question.